# Cause & Effect of over reving

Tags: transmission

What would be the effect on transmission shift on hard acceleration if all solenoids weren’t properly torqued in U660e transmission ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not sure if I understand your questions. Solenoids don't tend to be torqued, are you talking in general or about a specific component?

Comment: Sounds like you're slipping gears

Answer (score 0):

> Cause & Effect of over reving

The Cause is that the accelerator pedal ls push down,( or a problem with the computer in modern cars ) the effect is that the RPM's of the engine increase dramatically, which if revved to high for to long can cause internal damage to the engine.

If you shift the transmission into gear while the RPM's are high you will damage the transmission, ( *do not ask me how i know* )

I have no idea about what you are asking about in relation to

> Solenoids

.

Comment: Okay thank you for your valid response. The major problem with the shofts is  that when I try to go into a passing gear the transmission goes into neutral sending the engine ito high rev